# How to detect is the webpage loaded successfully in Xamarin using WebView

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using WebView to load a webpage in my app.(Implemented with Xamarin platform)

But I want to popup a message to user when the webpage loading is failed.(Maybe due to no internet)

How can I make it?

How can I detect the webpage is loaded succesfully or not?

Thank you.

Comment: Could it work ？

Answer (score 4):

You could use the WebView [Navigated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#events) event.

The `WebNavigatedEventArgs` object that accompanies the `Navigated` event has one propertie named `Result` which describes the result of the navigation, using a `WebNavigationResult` enumeration member. Valid values are `Cancel`, `Failure`, `Success`, and `Timeout`.

```
<StackLayout>
        <WebView x:Name="webView" Source="https://www.google.com" WidthRequest="1000" Navigated="webView_Navigated" HeightRequest="1000"  />
</StackLayout>

private async void webView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == WebNavigationResult.Failure)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Hi", "connect failure", "ok");
        }
        
    }
```